# How to make the @ symbol show up in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm trying to build a simple Rails app. Here's the relevant code from my seeds.db file:

```
tweets = Tweet.create([
    {handle: '@Name', content: 'My first tweet!'}
  ])
```

Everything seems to be displaying correctly, except the @ symbol between the quotes. Does anyone know how to make that show up on the page? Thanks

Comment: Has you tried to escape the character?
`tweets = Tweet.create([
    {handle: '\@Name', content: 'My first tweet!'}
  ])`

Comment: Alejandro, I just tried it after you suggested it, doesn't seem to work.

Comment: Did you try double quotes instead of single?

Comment: Akash, I did try double quotes.

Comment: Are you absolutely sure that the @ symbol is still in the handle attribute at the time you are rendering? Check in the database and check it in Rails console.

Answer (score 0):

You cold try to wrap your string in a double quote like this

```
tweets = Tweet.create([
    {handle: "@Name", content: "My first tweet!"}
  ])
```

I hope that this is able to help :)

Happy Coding